# XPages - saved computed fields on Notes form

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

On saving an XPage I would like to save all values of computed fields in the underlying Notes form. The reason is that when opening the document in the Notes client I want to have the values of this computed fields already saved in the document. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It should be a single line of SSJS in your save event.  I suspect that there is more to your issue, can you give examples of what you tried that isn't working.

Comment: Wow, I think Mr. Withers named all possible ways, hope you are all set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options.

1. Set the fields via SSJS / Java when the document is created and use the Computed Field bound to the underlying field.
2. Use additional HiddenInput fields, set accordingly.
3. Add code to store the values on save using getComponent("myText1").getValue(). If they need to be another data type than text, you'll need to convert them.
4. Use Computed Text on your Notes Client form, computed to the same as you have on your XPage.
5. Using an Edit Box with readonly="true" may work, I can't remember if that stores the value back or not.

The Computed Field control is really more analagous to Computed Text in the Notes Client world rather than a field that's computed. It allows setting various tags like h2, span etc, to allow a single control that's not a Label to display calculated content and have controlling properties like styleClass, loaded, rendered etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried first point 5 which unfortunately didn't work, so I solved my issue as suggested in point 1. On saving the XPage I now save also the value I need in the Notes document.